# Promoted Results not working on Enterprise farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have created a "Promoted Results" query rule which is working fine on two different farms, neither of which is a foundation installation and one has enterprise features neabled.

Now, on a third farm - also enterprise enabled - the the rule seems to have no effect. After having created the rule SharePoint-UI shows "Enterprise users only" under the name of the rule.
[image: "Enterprise users only"]

Any ideas, as to why this one Search Service Application might not show promoted results?

(The query is working fine and returning results if fired separately, so that's not an issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having set the ULS-Log for all search to verbose I found the following entry:

> 08.25.2016 14:22:10.18    w3wp.exe (0x3DD8)   0x5B00  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  ahrr8   Verbose **User is licensed for Enterprise Search: False**   353d9d9d-e59a-8052-93b7-a30f63613db7

The Reason for this was, that [`User-Licensing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx) was enabled on the farm in question and none of my test users were in any of the AD-groups granting licenses.

**Test for UserLicensing**

```
> Get-SPUserLicensing
True
```

Adding the users to the correct AD-Groups solved the problem.